# How to submit all grid values to the server at once with jQuery Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I looking to save all data from my grid to a server. I'm using jquery Datatables plugin.

```
function fnSave() {
    var aTrs = oTable.fnGetNodes();
    var aReturn = new Array();

    for(var i=0;i<aTrs.length;i++) {
        var aData=oTable.fnGetData(i);
        aReturn.push( aData );
    }

    console.log(aReturn);
}
```

As return I get :

```
"<input name="regimentNameAgents" value="" id="regimentNameAgents" type="text">"
...
```

I would like to only return grid values (and not HTML).

By using this function, my value is always: value="", even if I add text in the input, why?

Is there a better way to extract all grid data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data that's stored in the JDataTable isn't what's currently in the DOM, it's what you set it with originally. So when you update an input, the DOM element is updated, but there's no hook to update the data held in the jdatatable. I'd build the grid something more like this:

```
var grid = new Array();
$("table tr").each(function() {
    var nextRow = new Array();
    grid.push(nextRow);
    $("td", this).each(function() {
        var nextValue = $("input", this).val();
        nextRow.push(nextValue);
    });
});
```

The `grid` variable should then be storing your full table of data. I'm making a few assumptions about how you've structured your table there, since it wasn't posted, but I'm guessing that's fairly close to what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

By using Datatables fnGetNodes, here is the solution :

```
function fnSave() {

                   var aTrs = oTable.fnGetNodes();
                   var aReturn = new Array();

                   $(aTrs).each(function() {
                      var nextRow = new Array();
                      aReturn.push( nextRow );

                      $("td", this).each(function() {
                      var nextValue = $("input", this).val();
                      nextRow.push(nextValue);
                      });
                    });                  

                 console.log(aReturn);
}
```